# #define _UNICODE not working with MinGW + CodeBlocks

Tags: winapi, unicode, mingw, codeblocks

usually i use visual studio, but i switched to mingw, i like to make my apps easily changeable from unicode and multi byte, in my mingw project i have my defines and includes like this:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WINVER 0x0700
#define _UNICODE

#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define WND_MAIN_CLASS  _T("MainWindowFrame")
```

then i register and create my window e.g.

```
 WNDCLASSEX wc;
...
wc.lpszClassName = WND_MAIN_CLASS;

RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, WND_MAIN_CLASS, _T("Main Window"),
  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
  CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 640, 480, NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);
```

but when i go to compile i get errors that it cannot convert wchar_t to CHAR* on the WNDCLASSEX lpszClassName and the CreateWindowEx on the Class name and window title.

if i right click and go to declaration of createwindowex and WNDCLASSEX, it comes up with these from winuser.h:

```
    typedef WNDCLASSEXW WNDCLASSEX,*LPWNDCLASSEX,*PWNDCLASSEX;

#define CreateWindowEx CreateWindowExW
```

if i comment out the define _UNICODE it compiles and works with no problems

Comment: what's with that WINVER? I didn't know there was a Windows version 7.

Comment: lol, i thought that meant windows 7, oh well.. atleast everything should be included now its that high... what is the WINVER for windows 7? i thoguht vista was 0x0600 and xp 0x0500

Comment: @user394242: 2000 was 5.0, XP=5.1, 2003=5.2, Vista=6.0 and 7=6.1 (2008 is the same as VistaSP1: 6.0.6001 while VistaRTM's build number is 6000, this was the first time a service pack changed the OS version AFAIK)

Comment: If you want to use Unicode with MinGW, you will either need a wrapper or the `-municode` option. For details, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571250/wwinmain-unicode-and-mingw/11706847#11706847.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When compiling unicode apps you should probably define both `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE`. The windows headers use [UNICODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381407(v=vs.85).aspx) and the MS C runtime uses [_UNICODE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/12/71851.aspx)

Comment: And if you want to easily change between ANSI and Unicode, specify them in build options instead of defining them in the source.