# error C2731: 'wWinMain' : function cannot be overloaded

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, compiler-errors

I upgraded an old project from VC6 to VS2008, and now I get this compile error:

```
error C2731: 'wWinMain' : function cannot be overloaded
```

At these lines of code:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
```

The same project compiles fine under VC6.

Comment: It looks like a problem with default settings of compiler (unicode/non-unicode). Have you tried to switch this option in the converted project?

Comment: Which setting do I need to change? Preprocessor defines, linker settings? I want my project to be Unicode, not ASCII by the way. I had already set it up to be Unicode under VC6.

Comment: If you change it to just WinMain does it work? I dont think I've ever seen _tWinMain before.

Comment: As I understand, now you are migrating from ANSY to Unicode. Am I right? Usually it can't be done automatically. So, it is better to compile ANSY version now - to become sure, that everything works. And only after it you will migrate to ANSY+Unicode and to only Unicode versions (there are few articles about it on msdn.com).

Comment: @Ilya No, I'm migrating from Unicode/VC6 to Unicode/VS2008.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yes, `WinMain` works on VS2008. In VC6, both `WinMain` and `wWinMain` work, though. I'm reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571250/wwinmain-unicode-and-mingw, it talks about the difference between them.

Comment: (1) Project Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Character Set
(2) Project Properties->Linker->System->Sub-System: Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)
(3) Check `stdafx.h` to have `#include <tchar.h>` Posted as answer for the reason that these are standard checks we make when we port from VC6: they are not trial and errors

Comment: @elimad Thanks, I checked all 3, and indeed they are set exactly as you suggest (and tchar.h is included). Seems the problem is elsewhere. Don't forget, same project compiles fine under VC6.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I finally found the real culprit, it's a typo, I use `LPSTR lpCmdLine` instead of `LPTSTR lpCmdLine`. The real mystery is why it compiled at all under VC6 - it did use `wWinMain`, but somehow it was OK for lpCmdLine to be `char *` instead of `WCHAR *`.

Now I changed it to:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                       HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                       LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                       int       nCmdShow)
```

And it works under VS2008 too.

**Edit:** I successfully compiled and even ran the program with this function definition under VC6:

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(int *hInstance, float hPrevInstance, int *lpCmdLine, float nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(0,L"Running.",0,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly, replacing `float nCmdShow` to `double nCmdShow` does give a linker error, I assume because float is 32-bits but double is not.

Comment: The assurance of it getting successfully compiled in VC6 misled. Good find! Would also be of great help if you can figure out how it compiled in VC6. thanks

Comment: Probably `_UNICODE` was not set in VC6, so `LPTSTR` actually *was* `LPSTR` (and not `LPWSTR`).

Comment: My guess is that VC6 didn't distinguish between pointers as much as it should have. If `char* p; WCHAR* q; p = q;` compiles with VC6 without errors, then this would answer this question.

Answer (score 5):

For me it worked after changing WinMain to wWinMain in VS 2019

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with a *Win32 Console Application*. The fix was:

1. Open *Project* >  *Properties ...*,
2. Expand *Configuration Properties* > *Linker* > *System*
3. Set *SubSystem* to *Not Set*
4. Click *OK*

Comment: I have the same problem but it appeared without me changing my configuration, it's not the problem.