# Another undefined reference to WinMain@16 issue

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, mingw

On Code::Blocks 13.12, I used the wizard to create a DX9 project by starting a new project. I specified the DX folder and it doesn't complain. An auto-generated .cpp appears and it's set to GUI application, file is not set to read-only mode, and I hit compile:

> ||=== Build: Debug in xxxxxxxx (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>   c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1......\libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7)||undefined reference to `WinMain@16'|
>   ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|

Here's the full code that's auto-generated:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#define NOMINMAX
LPDIRECT3D9         g_pD3D = NULL; // Used to create the D3DDevice
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9   g_pd3dDevice = NULL; // Our rendering device

HRESULT InitD3D( HWND hWnd )
{
    if( NULL == ( g_pD3D = Direct3DCreate9( D3D_SDK_VERSION ) ) )
        return E_FAIL;

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory( &d3dpp, sizeof( d3dpp ) );
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;

    if( FAILED( g_pD3D->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd,
                                      D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                                      &d3dpp, &g_pd3dDevice ) ) )
    {
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    return S_OK;
}

VOID Cleanup()
{
    if( g_pd3dDevice != NULL )
        g_pd3dDevice->Release();

    if( g_pD3D != NULL )
        g_pD3D->Release();
}

VOID Render()
{
    if( NULL == g_pd3dDevice )
        return;

    // Clear the backbuffer to a blue color
    g_pd3dDevice->Clear( 0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB( 0, 0, 255 ), 1.0f, 0 );

    // Begin the scene
    if( SUCCEEDED( g_pd3dDevice->BeginScene() ) )
    {
        // Rendering of scene objects can happen here

        // End the scene
        g_pd3dDevice->EndScene();
    }

    // Present the backbuffer contents to the display
    g_pd3dDevice->Present( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
}

LRESULT WINAPI MsgProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch( msg )
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            Cleanup();
            PostQuitMessage( 0 );
            return 0;

        case WM_PAINT:
            Render();
            ValidateRect( hWnd, NULL );
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
}

INT WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, INT )
{
    // Register the window class
    WNDCLASSEX wc =
    {
        sizeof( WNDCLASSEX ), CS_CLASSDC, MsgProc, 0, 0,
        GetModuleHandle( NULL ), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
        "D3D Tutorial", NULL
    };
    RegisterClassEx( &wc );

    // Create the application's window
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow( "D3D Tutorial", "D3D Tutorial 01: CreateDevice",
                              WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 300, 300,
                              NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL );

    // Initialize Direct3D
    if( SUCCEEDED( InitD3D( hWnd ) ) )
    {
        // Show the window
        ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );
        UpdateWindow( hWnd );

        // Enter the message loop
        MSG msg;
        while( GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) )
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
    }

    UnregisterClass( "D3D Tutorial", wc.hInstance );
    return 0;
}
```

Before the same questions are asked before in answers where this may have been solved, here's what's been tried:

1.Restarted Code::Blocks; still gives the same error.

2.Tried GUI and console; still gives the same error.

3.Tried with a blank application; still gives the same error.

4.Tried with a Windows GUI application; still gives the same error.

I am **guaranteed** that the DX SDK is setup and the runtime is up-to-date and everything else of the related such. Any other suggestions to this issue?

Comment: The entry point makes no difference.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed you're using mingw.  Unfortunately, [mingw does *not* support `wWinMain` ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3571250).  You *must* use `WinMain` instead.

Comment: Oh, I guess that's out of date.  There seems to be support for it nowadays, try passing `-municode` to mingw.

Comment: I tried both suggestions above and it still gives the same error.

Comment: Wait, so if you try to compile a minimal program like `int WINAPI WinMain(...) { return 0; }`, it still complains with the same error?

Comment: Compiling the exact same program above gives the same error regardless of appending the 'w' or passing -municode. The program size seems not to be the problem. I'm trying with DirectX.

Comment: Please try compiling the minimal program `int WINAPI WinMain(...) { return 0; }` on the command line with `g++ program.cpp` and let us know what error you see (put it in the question if there's any thing new).

Comment: I am not trying to just compile a Windows API program; I'm trying to compile Windows API and DX9. There are no errors if DX is not included. When DX is set as a new project, it complains about WinMain@16.

Comment: Does a minimal program work if you compile without DX9?  If you do compile with DX9, what are the additional flags that you pass to the compiler and/or linker?

Comment: Give me two minutes to try without DX.

Comment: Compiles without error without DX includes. I pass no additional flags or change anything when adding DX except for -ld3d9 with the linker settings.

Comment: Of course, most of the original program is DX setup (D3D9 devices, heap cleanup, etc.). If the error points to WinMain@16 with DX setup and no error without, what the hell could be the issue?

Comment: This is 100% a linker-related issue. I'm not entirely sure why adding `-ld3d9` causes a minimal program to fail however and I don't have access to a Windows computer atm.  Perhaps try showing some more verbose output from the linker?

Comment: I gave the entire error and there's nothing more to show.

Comment: I'll just forget Code::Blocks and do it all manually without an IDE. Thanks for the help anyways, but the issue was not resolved. Code::Blocks has always been garbage and it's just too stressful to do anything with it.

Comment: Wait, so now it works without the IDE? (Also when I said verbose output, I meant you had to add some flags to the linker to make it show more output.)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this Microsoft monstrosity:

```
INT WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, INT )
```

with this standard C++ code:

```
int main()
```

That's it.

Your code appears to already be written for a standard `main`, e.g. you're using `GetModuleHandle( 0 )` instead of the `hInst` from `wWinMain`.

---

If you want UTF-16 encoded process command line, just call `GetCommandLine`, and possibly `CommandLineToArgvW` (IIRC) to parse it. MinGW-64 does support `wmain`, via a special option. But with the two functions mentioned you can implement the `wmain` support in five to six lines of code, so it doesn't really matter, and I'd rather write the code than using an obscure option.