# How can I convert an int to a string in C++11 without using to_string or stoi?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, gcc

I know it sounds stupid, but I'm using MinGW32 on Windows7, and "`to_string` was not declared in this scope." [It's an actual GCC Bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52015), and I've followed [these instructions](http://tehsausage.com/mingw-to-string) and they did not work. So, how can I convert an int to a string in C++11 without using `to_string` or `stoi`? (Also, I have the `-std=c++11` flag enabled).

Comment: Well, you could use MinGW-w64 instead which supports it

Comment: You could use `sprintf`. Actually there are a *lot* of options - `atoi` and company (not-quite-standard), string streams, the printf functions.

Comment: @MattMcNabb the question is about formatting ints to strings, not parsing strings to ints

Comment: `to_string` and `stoi` are the inverse of each other. Which is it you want to do?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos why did you mention `atoi` then

Comment: He probably meant `itoa`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its not the fastest method but you can do this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template<typename ValueType>
std::string stringulate(ValueType v)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << v;
    return oss.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << ("string value: " + stringulate(5.98)) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to answer it differently: just get mingw-w64.

Seriously, MinGW32 is just so full of issues it's not even funny:

- http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/1578/
- http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/message/23108552/
- [wWinmain, Unicode, and Mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571250/wwinmain-unicode-and-mingw)

With MinGW-w64 you get for free:

- support for Windows Unicode entry point (`wmain`/`wWinMain`)
- better C99 support
- better C++11 support (as you see in your question!)
- large file support
- support for C++11 threads
- support for Windows 64 bit
- cross compiling! so you can work on your Windows app on your favorite platform.

Comment: As of MinGW-w64 4.9.2, C++14 is also supported (and C11 too IIRC).

Comment: Ok, you've convinced me haha.. I'll uninstall it and download mingw-w64.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stringstream`.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 12345;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << num;
    string str;
    ss >> str;
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could roll your own function to do it.

```
std::string convert_int_to_string (int x) {
  if ( x < 0 )
    return std::string("-") + convert_int_to_string(-x);
  if ( x < 10 )
    return std::string(1, x + '0');
  return convert_int_to_string(x/10) + convert_int_to_string(x%10);
}
```

Comment: "You could" != "You should". Just pointing out one other possible thing.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that previous answers are better I want to give you another possibility to implement an INT to STRING method following the next old school code:

```
#include <string>

std::string int2string(int value) {
    char buffer[20]; // Max num of digits for 64 bit number
    sprintf(buffer,"%d", value);
    return std::string(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Will cause a buffer overflow on a system with 64-bit ints

Comment: Nop, beacuse 64bit needs 19 digits (in the example there are  20 digit buffer) 

9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (19 digits)

Comment: You forgot about the minus sign

Comment: Nop, because buffer has 20 bytes for 19 digits (1 byte extra for sign)

Comment: You forgot about the null terminator