# Can not compile win32 C++ Using Mingw

Tags: c++, mingw

I wanted to start learning win32 api but the g++ would always return with

```
undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

I copied my cpp code from microsoft's website from here - [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program). I tried multiple other sources of "Hello World" but without luck. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with two types of entry-point functions in WinAPI: `WinMain` and `wWinMain`.

> The `WinMain` function is identical to `wWinMain`, except the command-line arguments are passed as an ANSI string. The Unicode version is preferred.

Source: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/winmain--the-application-entry-point)

Both should work well with Microsoft Visual C++ compiler. However, there are some problems with MinGW and `wWinMain` function.

**Solution 1**: Use Microsoft Visual C++ compiler.

**Solution 2**: Use MinGW and change your entry-point function to `WinMain` because it works correctly on MinGW (also change `PWSTR pCmdLine` to `PSTR pCmdLine`):

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
           ^^^^^^^                                 ^^^^
```

**Solution 3**: It is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11706847/7389107) but I didn't test it.
If you are using MinGW-w64, you can add
`-municode` as your command line option. Your original source code should be compiled correctly.

Comment: Solution 2 and 3 didn't work for me. WinMain function is already defined and it passes error. For solution 3, it worked on basic code but didn't work great. Solution 1 worked all good.